# How to fire event when user logged in with Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I had setup

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="400" data-max-rows="1" scope="email, publish_stream"></div><script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'xxx', // App ID
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML,
        oauth : true
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
            // app, and response.authResponse supplies
            // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
            // request, and the time the access token 
            // and signed request each expire
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

            // TODO: Handle the access token

            $.post('/facebook/login', { accessToken: accessToken }, function (response) { if(response) {alert('Logged in')} });

        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
            // but has not authenticated your app
        } else {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        }
    });


};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document));
```

The problem is when user click on Login button and Accept my app, the login dialog is closed and no event is fired so my post $.post('/facebook/login') also never fired unless I press F5.

How can I fire event right after login dialog box closed?

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing.
Run in to a possible solution while reading Facebook documentation for answers.

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3548493/how-to-detect-when-facebooks-fb-init-is-complete

You could run your $.post('/facebook/login') inside fbEnsureInit(); <-- referring to serg's answer.

Using an interval callback to check for login status might be a way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can reload the page with: `window.location.reload();` so you don't need to press F5,

An FB.login example:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log('Application authorized.');
        window.location.reload();
    } else {
        console.log('You cancelled login or you did not fully authorize the app.');
    }
}, { scope: 'email' });
```

or you can use a subscribe event:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    console.log('The status of the session changed to: '+response.status);
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: @holyredbeard it's an old answer (May 2012) and Facebook made a lot of changes all this months. I think that down-voting an old answer it's not the best you can do! Why you are not opening a new question for your problem?

Comment: @holyredbeard Take a look here for more info about FB.Login(): http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: @holyredbeard, i found some free time to check this and i have to inform you that it works fine. How you call the FB.login? on each load maybe? If you remove the "window.location.reload();", it's fixing your problem?

Comment: Yes, removing window.location.reload(); fixed the infinite loop and solved the problem, so I suppose I implemented the function the wrong way. If you may you could edit your answer so it's possible for me to change the vote.

Comment: Sorry i can't, because the question asked here by @vNext it's about how to refresh the page after a successful login/event and this can be done with: window.location.reload()